# Make the maximum sum in a interval.

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

Two players $A$ and $B$ are playing a game with array $A$ of $N$ elements in which each player chooses an array interval with maximum sum. The other simultaneously chooses another interval in the same array such that both the chosen intervals follow certain rules:

1. Two chosen intervals shouldn't have anything between them. That is, they should not be overlapping.
2. Two intervals chosen shouldn't be too close to each other. There must be at least K index distance between the finish of the first interval and the start of the second interval.
3. The sum of the values in chosen intervals should be as big as possible. Or we can say both chosen intervals sum should be as large as possible.

Example:

Let $N=8$, $K=3$, and $A=\{5, 5, -1, -2, 3, -1, 2, -2\}$. It is optimal to choose $[1, 2]$ and $[7, 7]$ intervals. That is the only optimal choice that we can make.

And total sum if $10$(from first interval) $+ 2$(from second interval) $= 12$.

Comment: i think there exist special algorithm for this,wait a minute please

Comment: What is your question about this game?

Comment: is this what you were searching @user3001932 ?

Comment: @Hen Wolff I want the maximum sum they both can obtain together

Comment: @ dato datuashvili Actually your proposed algorithm is just a naive approach.I want a efficient algorithm to handle large N an K(say of order 10^5).

Comment: it is not my proposed,on the link there is more elegant solution,http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/maxsum.c

Comment: that why i have told use stackoverflow for this  programming question